# Check if number(s) is prime in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, primes

I'm doing an online challenge and came across one problem! I have worked out the logic on paper, but it seems my problem doesn't work. All it does is return 0 as output.

My code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int nums[50];
    string res[50];
    int o = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> nums[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int deliteli=1;
        for(int j=1;j<=nums[i];j++)
        {
            if(nums[i]%j==0)
            {
                deliteli++;
            }
        }
        if(deliteli == 2){
            res[0] = "YES";
            o++;
        }
        else if(deliteli != 2){
            res[0] = "NO";
            o++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<o;i++)
    {
        cout << res[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I am doing is firstly input N number, which means how long the array is going to be and then check for each number in the array whether it's prime or not. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `res[0] = 'YES'` is not right.

Comment: Mhm, I tried " and it seems to work, but it only outputs one, which is wrong as well. When do we use ' and when do we use "?

Comment: `'` is for **single characters only** (the fact that it compiles doesn't say much, C++ is like that sometimes). `"` is for strings.

Comment: You may also be interested in the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) algorithm for detection of primes.

Comment: @Dukeling `'` with more than one character is allowed in C++. What is does in practice is implementation defined.

Comment: @john I'm saying C++ is happy with it, but you should never do it.

Comment: @Dukeling Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `deliteli` should start at 0.
- `deliteli` should be reset at the beginning of the loop.
- You use `res[i]` instead of `res[0]`, otherwise you keep overwriting the first element.
- `j%nums[i]` should be `nums[i]%j`, because `a%b` returns the remainder from dividing `a` by `b`.
- `'` is for single characters only (C++ is perfectly happy allowing things that shouldn't be allowed to compile and run). `"` is for strings.

Final code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int nums[50];
    string res[50];
    int o = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> nums[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int deliteli=0;
        for(int j=1;j<=nums[i];j++)
        {
            if(nums[i]%j==0)
            {
                deliteli++;
            }
        }
        if(deliteli == 2){
            res[i] = "YES";
            o++;
        }
        else if(deliteli != 2){
            res[i] = "NO";
            o++;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<o;i++)
    {
        cout << res[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/7Fnnkd).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I noticed my mistakes... the reason deliteli started from 1 was because my original idea was to go until number/2 because the rest of the numbers will give the same answer, so the program doesn't waste more time. As for the res[0], it was meant to be res[o], thus the o was increasing afterwards. I appreciate your help! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int j=1;j>=nums[i];j++)
{
   ...
}
```

It seems like you have the loop condition wrong. It should be:

```
for(int j=1;j<=nums[i];j++) //Change here
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to initialize deliteli inside the loop.

Comment: Tried that as well, same result. I declared it in the first for (i).

Comment: You set res[0] = 'YES', I think you might want to add res[o] = 'YES' instead. I have a high level comment for you, instead of posting this question on stackExchange, you should either use a debugger (gdb) or use print statements to help you debug through the program. Best way to learn is to identify problems yourself and fix it. Try your program on simple examples to see what is wrong and why that might be. If you are still stuck then come to stackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

To check if `nums[i]` can be divided by `j` you are doing `j%nums[i]==0`, but that needs to be `nums[i]%j==0`.

Your `deliteli` counter also has a problem.
You need to reinitialize it for each number, otherwise it will just add to it.

Also you are always setting `res[0]`, but you would want to set `res[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

first: to check if `nums[i]` can be divided by `j` you are doing `j%nums[i]==0`, but that needs to be `nums[i]%j==0`.

second: 
change `for(int j=1;j>=nums[i];j++)`
to `for(int j=1;j<=nums[i];j++)`

and last: **you don't have** to test number `nums[i]` up to `nums[i]` but **just to square root** of this so change it to `sqrt(nums[i])+1`. It might be slight improvement to the speed of your algorithm.

Comment: All of the changes you said were made before your post and that didn't fix the problem.. as for the square root one, I'll do it after I make it work this way.. thanks! Updated first post with current code.

Comment: this is really important if your numbers are going to be bigger

Comment: How about going to num/2 instead of doing square root?

Comment: this will result in worse performance as 0.5x>=sqrt(x) for all x>4

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example with a real number?

Comment: take x=16; if you use x/2=16/2=8 you will determine if 16 is divided by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. if you use sqrt(16)=4 you try only 1,2,3,4

Comment: I understand, however the sqrt method won't work if I want to find how many divisors a number has totally. In this case it will do the job though I believe!

Comment: @JohnSmith sqrt() will return all devisors, remember: if you found that x1 is divisor ox Y (x1 is <sqrt(Y)) then corresponding x2 >sqrt(Y) is x2=Y/x1. it is all